# Refresh an element with jQuery .load function without duplicating it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the user clicks the submit button, the div `.forum` is supposed to refresh (without refreshing the page). However, for some reason it instead creates a new div `.forum` inside the original div, like ths:

[image]

While I am aware that I can prevent this by adding a container around the div `.forum`, I was wondering if there's an option which means I don't need a container div?

```
<div class="forum">
<form id="theforum">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>

<script>
$(document).on("submit", "#theforum", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(".forum").load(location.href + " .forum");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try with    $(".forum").load(location.href + " .forum *");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test if this works right now but i believe it solves your problem:

```
$(".forum").load(location.href + " .forum > *");
```

This way you're not grabbing the div itself, but its contents.

Answer (score 1):

The load function loads the response of a different page and dumps it in the given element.
So to update the .forum div delete the old .forum and then load the new one and dump it into the parent of the (just deleted) '.forum'.

```
$(document).on("submit", "#theforum", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.forum').remove()  
   $("##FORUMS PARENT TAG##").load(location.href + " .forum");
});
```

Good luck!

For reference:
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned I would prefer not to add a container/parent around `.forum`. Is there another way?