# AJAX call returns wrong URLs in the HTML returned

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to reload my comments on a blog post with `ajax` when the pagination buttons are clicked. The `url` before the pagination is clicked looks like this

http://localhost/designv2/blog/read/3/lorem-ipsum/1/

If I then click on a page number in the pagination the `url`'s `ajax` return in the HTML will look like this

http://localhost/designv2/modules/blog_comments.php/1/

So **blog_comments.php** is the file `ajax` is calling to get the comments and that is probably why it is set as the `url` in all returned links.

How do i send the `url` assigned to href on the link to the page `ajax` calls for to get the right page number with comments and then set the url to the correct one?

```
$(".comments__pagination a").on("click", function() {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the page from reloading
    var blog_id = $(".blog__comment").attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "modules/blog_comments.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            reload_comments: "true",
            blog_id: blog_id
        },
        // On success output the requested site.
        success: function (data) {
            $(".blog__comment").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `on("click", function() {` should be `on("click", function(event) {` for it to work properly otherwise the `event.preventDefault();` doesn't work

Comment: Yeah thanks! but, that dosent not fix the url problem unfortunately.

Comment: The solution will not be in the code that you provided, but in the PHP code that generates the HTML on the server. What are the  `href` values in the `data` string?

Comment: You said you want to send with AJAX the URL in your href but you are sending the "id" attribute, not the "href"...

Comment: <a href="/designv2/blog/read/3/lorem-ipsum/2/">2</a> here is the href value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JQuery attr function you have to get href attribute

```
$(".comments__pagination a").on("click", function(event) {
 event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the page from reloading
 var blog_id = $(".blog__comment").attr("id");
 pageurl = $(this).attr("href");
  $.ajax({
    url: pageurl,
    type: "post",
    data: {
        reload_comments: "true",
        blog_id: blog_id
    },
    // On success output the requested site.
    success: function (data) {
        $(".blog__comment").html(data);
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: That will reload the whole page inside the div container tho. not only the comments. But i guess i can just replace the whole page and not just the comment container.

Comment: @Rajohan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47991946/refresh-an-element-with-jquery-load-function-without-duplicating-it